# Django radiobutton

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to access the value via Django from the value attribute of radio buttons that is generated by JavaScript. In the Django examples that i have found they use tuples which hard coded choices which doesn't work for me.

I want to do something like this.

```
formData = request.POST
value = formData[ "radiobuttonName" ].value
```

Context : Trying to make exam app that allows user to create exam and add as many answers he wants and then select with radio button which answers is right.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Marcin are you sure this works at all? I get errors when I try it.

Comment: @ViktorBlöndal: The code won't work, because it's not a serious attempt at code. It's an example of what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood your problem, but I think that the dictionary `request.POST` already contains the values you need. For example, `request.POST['radioButton']` is the `value` attribute of the selected radio button with that name.